# How often should the CMPS11 be calibrated?

Tags: calibration, magnetometer

I have a project with arduino and the magnetometer CMPS11. I wanted to know how often the CMPS11 should be calibrated using this procedure: https://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/cmps11i2c.htm

Comment: Identify the chip used. Get the data sheet and read what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calibration of the CMPS11 for horizontal only operation. So it should not have an issue if you do not calibrate it often. As tilt does not need calibration.